# psexec could not start psexec service on <server>. Error in the remote procedure call was cancelled

Tags: psexec

I get this error when running any command using psexec to a Win2012 server:

```
PsExec.exe -u <user> -p <pass> \\<server_ip> cmd.exe

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Could not start PSEXESVC service on <server_ip>:
Error in the remote procedure call was cancelled
```

I tried the following:

- put the **user** and **password** before the **machine name**
- put the **machine name** before the **user** and **password**
- use the server **IP**
- user the server **name**
- register the connection with `net use` before trying to run the command
- add the credentials with `cmdkey`

All of this with no success.

Things to take into account:

- Some other person tries the command and works for her, apparently.
- The user I use to connect to the machine **is not a local user**, but an Active Directory user of some **domain** (I am not allowed to use local users).